# Receive push messages and use content in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I'm new with MVC and I want to create a MVC4 Web Api that receives push messages (HTTP Post) with content in the request body and use it to save in the DB.

Right now I have this code (Just pass the content to the view instead of saving in DB):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string data;
    using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
        data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    data = data.Split('\"')[1];

    //var x = data;
    ViewBag.Message = data;

    return View();
}
```

My question is how can I force the controller to get the content in the method signature, for example, if the content exist in parameter called data:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string data)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can Bind the data into a `Model` and then use it or even simply you can pass the string from the View

**Code Sample
View**

```
@model MVCFormsExample.ViewModels.BookViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create Book";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)

</div>

<button type="submit">Create</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
`[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(BookViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // TODO: Save book
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }'
```

**OR**
**VIEW**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Show", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { uid = 1, uname = "user1" }))
{
<input type="submit" value="+"/>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public string Show(int? uid, string uname)
{
return uname + uid.ToString();
}
```

for WEB API you can follow **[This Link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)**

Comment: Thanks, but I get the post request from an outsource service, not from the view, so I still have to read the content. Am I right?

Comment: so how can I bind the data into the model if the content doesn't being send from the view?

Comment: For that model will not be used I said you need WEB API

Comment: This post will help you get started http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: posted the link for the same.